# The number of columns and rows of VR video in HEVC tiling

Tags: video, streaming, tile, virtual-reality, hevc

I have heard that "in HEVC tiling, all columns must have the same number of rows". Maybe it is not "must", it is "should" instead. I just want to know which reliable science paper can confirm that information.

If anyone knows, please send me the source.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In HEVC, tiling is configured as a grid (number of columns x number of rows). So, all columns have the same number of rows. If you want to achive columns with different number of rows, you can achieve that with a combination of slicing and tiling.